# Matlab Vector division : I want to know how matlab divided the two vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I was doing some programming on Matlab and i stumbled upon this part in the code:

[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]/[  1 3 4 7 9 11 13 15]

ans = 0.0939

I wanted to know how exactly did it compute this division

Thank you for your time,

I tried dividing element by element and i tried summing elementts of each vector and dividing it

Comment: The element-wise division is `./` -- this is probably the operation you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` operator is an alias for `mrdivide`, which has [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html).

> x = B/A solves the system of linear equations x*A = B for x. The matrices A and B must contain the same number of columns. MATLAB® displays a warning message if A is badly scaled or nearly singular, but performs the calculation regardless.
>
> - If A is a scalar, then B/A is equivalent to B./A.
> - If A is a square n-by-n matrix and B is a matrix with n columns, then x = B/A is a solution to the equation x*A = B, if it exists.
> - **If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a matrix with n columns, then x = B/A returns a least-squares solution of the system of equations x*A = B.**

Emphasis mine, for the case which you are showing, where `A` is a rectangular m-by-n matrix (m=1, n=8) and `B` is a matrix with n=8 columns.

So your result is the "*least-squares solution of the system `x*A=B`*", where you have `x=0.0939`.

You can visualise this as finding the minimum of

```
norm([1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] - X*[ 1 3 4 7 9 11 13 15])
```

i.e.

```
x = 0:0.001:0.3;
y = arrayfun( @(X) norm([1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] - X*[ 1 3 4 7 9 11 13 15]), x );
figure; plot( x, y )
```

(Note MATLAB is not doing this plot under the hood, this is purely a visualisation to convince yourself what the operation represents)

[image: plot]